# What is the significance of operating on random variables. Like finding E[x^2 + 3]

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

I had read the wiki page about moments. But still unable to get the real life significance.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)

It also says the second moment of the distribution is the variance. Does it mean E[x^2] is the variance ??

I also know variance is E[x^2]-(E[x])^2.

I am lost. Any input will help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The second moment of $X$ **about the mean** is the variance. So if $\mu=E(X)$ is the mean, then the variance of $X$ is 
$$E((X-\mu)^2), \quad\text{or equivalently}\quad E((X-E(X))^2)\tag{1}.$$

The above is the usual *definition* of variance. However, a not very hard computation shows that  the variance is always equal to 
$$E(X^2)-(E(X))^2.\tag{2}$$
The expression (2) for the variance is often more convenient for calculations than the more fundamental expression (1).

Comment: Thanks a lot André Nicolas. Apart from that is there any significance in performing computations on a random variable X?.

Comment: I also want to know that.

Comment: It is kind of difficult to answer that, since a large part of probability theory is oncerned precisely with operations on random variables. It turns out that "algebraic" manipulations of random variables are useful in answering many theoretical and practical questions. At he time that I did statistical consulting, they were, almost literally, my bread and butter. Well, more like my source of good wine, since brad and butter was covered by a conventional academic job.

Comment: Oh! thanks once again. Finally, are these arithmetic operations a way to actually link important parameters like expected value and the actual discrete probabilities?.

Comment: Yes, algebra (and calculus) link all these quantities. I should really give a fuller answer, but that would involve going through all of probability theory. As a simple example, if we repeat an experiment independently $n$ times, and the results are the random variables $X_1$ to $X_n$, then the sample mean is the algebraic expression $\frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n}{n}$. Properties of addition of random variables are crucial in the analysis of experimental results.

Comment: Often, the result of an experiment can be thought of as a random variable $X$, say the radius $X$ of a randomly chosen raindrop. We may know a great deal about the distribution of $X$, but may be interested in the *volume* of the raindrop. This is given by the function $\frac{4}{3}\pi X^3$ of the random variable $X$. Functions of random variables are everywhere. It is hard to find examples in probability/statistics where we are **not** studying functions of one or more random variables.